# Is there a way to rewrite this?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, c++11, visual-c++

```
string toLowerCase(string word)
{

  for (int a = 0; a < word.length(); a++)
  {

      if (word[a] >= 'A' && word[a] <= 'Z')
      {

          word[a] = word[a] + 32;
      }
  }


  return word;
}
```

Is there another way to code this? It can't be c-strings. Thanks.

Comment: How does your current thinking go about when you try yourself? There is some system in what you see, isn't there? Hint. space (`' '`) `==` `32`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as you haven't shown any effort to try to do it yourself.

Rewrite it to _what_?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some simplifications:

```
for (int a = 0; a < word.length(); a++) 
// can be replaced with
for (auto &letter : word)
```

```
if (word[a] >= 'A' && word[a] <= 'Z')
// can be replaced with
if (std::isupper(letter))
```

```
word[a] = word[a] + 32;
// can be replaced with
letter = std::tolower(letter);
```